# error in 'setDT' when reading csv file from s3 bucket in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I've below code to read a file from s3 into spark framework and to anonymize the data in the file

```
library(data.table)
library(digest)


ct_test <- spark_read_csv(
  sc,
  name = "test_data",
  memory = FALSE,
  path = "s3://XXXXXXX/sunny/Sample_data.csv",
  header = TRUE, 
  delimiter = ",",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE

)

cols_to_mask <- c("Email","Phone")

anonymize <- function(x, algo="crc32") {
  sapply(x, function(y) if(y == "" | is.na(y)) "" else digest(y, algo = algo))
}

setDT(ct_test)
ct_test[, (cols_to_mask) := lapply(.SD, anonymize), .SDcols = cols_to_mask]

print(ct_test)
```

But code is failing with below error

```
Error in setDT(ct_test) : 
  All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length, but the profile of input lengths (length:frequency) is: [1:1, 2:1]
The first entry with fewer than 2 entries is 1
> ct_test[, (cols_to_mask) := lapply(.SD, anonymize), .SDcols = cols_to_mask]
Error in `:=`((cols_to_mask), lapply(.SD, anonymize)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
>
```

Any help to fix the issue much appreciated

Below is the output from str(ct_test)

```
$ ops:List of 2
  ..$ x   : 'ident' chr "cx_data"
  ..$ vars: chr [1:5] "ID" "Name" "Email" "Phone" ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "op_base_remote" "op_base" "op"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl"
```

Input data set

```
ID,Name,Email,Phone,Survey
10,Ravi,test@gmail.com,874589,Survey 1
20,John,abc@gmail.com,878756,Survey 2
30,Smith,tt@yahoo.com,565656,Survey 3
40,Kevin,,,Survey 3
```

As suggested, changed  the code as below

```
cx_data <- spark_read_csv(
  sc,
  name = "cx_data",
  memory = FALSE,
  path = "s3://xxxx/sunny/Sample_data.csv",
  delimiter = ",",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  #infer_schema = FALSE


)
test_data <-fread(cx_data)
```

But now failing with below error

```
Error in fread(cx_data) : 
  input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space
```

Comment: Below is the output from str(ct_test)

$ ops:List of 2
  ..$ x   : 'ident' chr "cx_data"
  ..$ vars: chr [1:5] "ID" "Name" "Email" "Phone" ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "op_base_remote" "op_base" "op"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl"

Comment: updated the post with str(ct_test) output results

Comment: i think your data looks like `data.table(x="cx_data", vars=c("ID","Name","Email","Phone","LastColumn"))`

Comment: Yes, ive updated the post with the input data set, I'm not sure why setDT giving issues,

Comment: how about `as.data.table(ct_test$ops)`? i can read the input data set with `fread`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212222/discussion-between-npk-and-chinsoon12).

Comment: sorry no access

Comment: not able to use the fread, updated the post with the error

Comment: I was referring to your Input Data Set when I mentioned fread